# CSS: width behavior change when including bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I recently noticed that CSS property width does not have the same effect when using bootstrap. Could someone know why?

I use firefox developer console to inspect box model and see actual dimensions.

Simple html code:

```
<div style="width=400px;height=30px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle with a simple div with a fixed width/height. Its sized 404*34

https://jsfiddle.net/nszvxfwq/

Here the same one including bootstrap. You can see the box size to be 400*30

https://jsfiddle.net/nszvxfwq/1/

Comment: Because bootstrap applies [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150224/#propdef-box-sizing) to all elements, whereas your example retains the initial box-sizing value of content box (which draws padding & border outside of the specified width & height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Adrift, your answert really helped me!

> Because bootstrap applies box-sizing: border-box; to all elements, whereas  >your example retains the initial box-sizing value of content box (which draws >padding & border outside of the specified width & height). –  Adrift yesterday